# Analytical solution for this PDE?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, analytic-functions

I am interested in finding the analytical solution of the following PDE, but I am not sure if it has one.

$$\frac{\partial{h}}{\partial{t}}=\gamma\nabla.(h\nabla h)$$ 
$$\implies\frac{\partial{h}}{\partial{t}}=\gamma\left[\nabla h.\nabla h + h\nabla^2 h\right]$$ 
Boundary conditions:
$$\lim_{r \to 0} \left[2\pi r\gamma h \frac{\partial{h}}{\partial{r}}\right]=-a$$
$$[n.(\gamma h\nabla h)]_{r_n}=0$$

In above equations, $\gamma$ and $a$ are constants.

[Domain describing $h(x,y,t), r, x, y, z$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyOza.png)

I need the analytical solution for the above PDE in order to optimize the equation in terms of its time series for some fixed spatial coordinate.